# arraylist.remove() on adapter deletes wrong item in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

I have an `Adapter` called `AdapterActions` that extends `ArrayAdapter<Action>`. I give an `ArrayList<Action>` to the `AdapterActions` and it fills a `ListView` with that ArrayList. The problem is this:

Let's suppose this is my ArrayList:

```
ListaActions(0) = a
ListaActions(1) = b
ListaActions(2) = c
ListaActions(3) = d
ListaActions(4) = e
```

And I do `ListaActions.remove(2)` and then I clear and re-add every `Action` object to `ListaActions`, it succesfully removes the third object from the ArrayList, but in the ListView it removes the LAST item (in this case it would be ListaActions(4)'s view) and it sets every property of the removed object (ListaActions(4)) represented on that ListView to its default value, i.e.: int properties to 0, boolean properties to true...

When I close the app and then I open it again, it's still the same, it doesn't "refresh" the ListView. Any idea?

I've read some posts about `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but I don't think it could work if what it does is to "Notify that the Data Set changed", if when I restart the app it rebuilds everything and those "empty" views are still there and the last object on the ArrayList isn't being represented in the listview.

This is the code of the `AdapterActions`:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Switch;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    /*@SuppressLint("ViewHolder") */public class AdapterActions extends ArrayAdapter<Action>{

        // our ViewHolder.
        // caches our TextView
        static class ViewHolderItem {
            TextView codigo;
            TextView accion;
            TextView evento;
            Switch UnSwitch;
            boolean isChecked1;
        }

        Activity context;
        ArrayList<Action> listaActions;
        @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays") Map <Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

        // Le pasamos al constructor el contexto y la lista de contactos
        public AdapterActions(Activity context, ArrayList<Action> listaActions) {
            super(context, R.layout.layout_adapter_actions, listaActions);
            this.context = context;
            this.listaActions = listaActions;




        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

            // Rescatamos cada item del listview y lo inflamos con nuestro layout
            //View item = convertView;
            //item = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter_actions, null);
            // well set up the ViewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();

            if(convertView==null){

                // inflate the layout
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_adapter_actions, parent, false);

                // well set up the ViewHolder
                viewHolder.codigo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.codigo);
                viewHolder.accion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.accion);
                viewHolder.evento = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.evento);
                viewHolder.UnSwitch = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activa);
                convertView.setLongClickable(true);

                // store the holder with the view.
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            }else{
                // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
                // just use the viewHolder
                viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Action a = new Action(0, 1, 1, true);
            AccionDefinida LaAccion = new AccionDefinida(0, 0, "", "");
            EventoDefinido ElEvento = new EventoDefinido(0, 0, "", "");

            //ACTIONS
                    ActionsSQLite base = new ActionsSQLite(context, "Actions", null,1);
                    SQLiteDatabase db1 = base.getReadableDatabase();
                    db1 = context.openOrCreateDatabase("Actions",SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);

                    String query = "SELECT * FROM Actions WHERE Id = " + String.valueOf(position + 1);
                    Cursor c1 = db1.rawQuery(query, null);

                    try{
                        if(c1!=null){

                            int i = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Id");
                            int j = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdAccionDefinida");
                            int k = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdEventoDefinido");
                            int l = c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Activa");
                            boolean esActiva;

                            //Nos aseguramos de que existe al menos un registro
                            while(c1.moveToNext()){
                                if (c1.getInt(l) == 0){
                                    esActiva = false;
                                } else
                                {
                                    esActiva = true;
                                }
                                //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                                a = new Action(c1.getInt(i), c1.getInt(j), c1.getInt(k), esActiva);
                            }
                        }
                        else 
                            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), 
                                      "No hay nada :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      }
                      catch (Exception e){
                        Log.i("bdActions", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e); 
                      }

                      if(db1!=null){
                            db1.close();
                    }   


            //EVENTOS
            EventosDefinidosSQLite base2 = new EventosDefinidosSQLite(this.context, "EventosDefinidos", null, 1);
            SQLiteDatabase db2 = base2.getReadableDatabase();
            db2 = context.openOrCreateDatabase("EventosDefinidos",SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);

            String query2 = "SELECT * FROM EventosDefinidos WHERE Id = " + a.getIdEventoDefinido();
            Cursor c2 = db2.rawQuery(query2, null);
            try{
                if(c2!=null){

                    int h = c2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Id");
                    int k = c2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdEvento");
                    int i = c2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Nombre");
                    int j = c2.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Aux");

                    //Nos aseguramos de que existe al menos un registro
                    while(c2.moveToNext()){
                        //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                        ElEvento = new EventoDefinido(c2.getInt(h), c2.getInt(k), c2.getString(i), c2.getString(j));
                    }
                }
                else 
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), 
                          "No hay nada :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("bdEventos", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e); 
            }

            if(db2!=null){
                db2.close();
            }   
            //ACCIONES
            AccionesDefinidasSQLite base3 = new AccionesDefinidasSQLite(context, "AccionesDefinidas", null,1);
            SQLiteDatabase db3 = base3.getReadableDatabase();
            db3 = context.openOrCreateDatabase("AccionesDefinidas", SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY, null);

            String query3 = "SELECT * FROM AccionesDefinidas WHERE Id = " + String.valueOf(a.getIdAccionDefinida());
            Cursor c3 = db3.rawQuery(query3, null);
            try{
                if(c3!=null){

                    int h = c3.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Id");
                    int k = c3.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IdAccion");
                    int i = c3.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Nombre");
                    int j = c3.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Aux");

                    //Nos aseguramos de que existe al menos un registro
                    while(c3.moveToNext()){
                        //Recorremos el cursor hasta que no haya más registros
                        LaAccion = new AccionDefinida(c3.getInt(h), c3.getInt(k), c3.getString(i), c3.getString(j));
                    }
                }
                else 
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), 
                          "No hay nada :(", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("bdAcciones", "Error al abrir o crear la base de datos" + e); 
            }

            if(db3!=null){
                db3.close();
            }

            // object item based on the position


            // assign values if the object is not null
            if(a != null) {
                // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
                viewHolder.codigo.setText(String.valueOf(a.getId()));
                viewHolder.codigo.setTag(a.getId());
                viewHolder.accion.setText(LaAccion.getNombre());
                viewHolder.evento.setText(ElEvento.getNombre());
                viewHolder.UnSwitch.setChecked(a.getActiva());
                Log.e("Position+1: "+ String.valueOf(position+1), "Id: "+ String.valueOf(a.getId()));


            }

            viewHolder.isChecked1 = viewHolder.UnSwitch.isChecked();
            map.put(position, viewHolder.isChecked1);
            viewHolder.UnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("OnClick", "Se clickeó");

                    listaActions.get(position).setActiva(map.get(position));
                    Log.e("Listener del switch", "Modificó la action en la lista de la ActividadPrincipal");
                    int isActiva;
                    if(map.get(position) == true)
                    {
                        isActiva = 0;
                        Log.e("Listener del switch", "isActiva = 1");
                        map.put(position, false);
                    } else
                    {
                        isActiva = 1;
                        Log.e("Listener del switch", "isActiva = 0");
                        map.put(position, true);
                    }
                    String query = "UPDATE Actions SET Activa = " + String.valueOf(isActiva) + " WHERE Id = " + String.valueOf(position+1);
                    Log.e("Consulta:", query);
                    Log.e("Listener del switch", "query creado");
                    Log.e("La position debería ser", String.valueOf(position+1));
                    Log.e("Y el valor del map.get(position) es", String.valueOf(map.get(position)));
                    ActionsSQLite helper1  = new ActionsSQLite(context, "Actions", null, 1);
                    Log.e("Listener del switch", "Creo el helper");
                    SQLiteDatabase db = helper1.getWritableDatabase();
                    Log.e("Listener del switch", "obtenida la base escribible");
                    db.execSQL(query);
                    Log.e("Listener del switch", "Query ejecutado");
                }
            });



            return convertView;


        }
```

And when I delete an object from that ArrayList, I do it from this Dialog:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class DialogModificarAction extends DialogFragment
{    

    public interface DialogModificarActionListener { 

        }



    private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, ArrayList<String> MiLista){

        int index = 0;

            for(int j = 0;j<=MiLista.size();j++){
            if (spinner.getSelectedItem().equals(MiLista.get(j))){
                index = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
}

    private Button cancelButton;
    private Button confirmButton;
    private Button deleteButton;
    private Spinner spinnerAccion;
    private Spinner spinnerEvento;
    private static Action ActionAModificar = null;
    private ArrayList<EventoDefinido> ListaEventosDefinidos = new ArrayList<EventoDefinido>();
    private ArrayList<AccionDefinida> ListaAccionesDefinidas = new ArrayList<AccionDefinida>();
    private ArrayList<String> ListaNombresAccionesDefinidas = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> ListaNombresEventosDefinidos = new ArrayList<String>();

    public DialogModificarAction()
    {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }    
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private DialogModificarActionListener dialogListener;


    //This is how you can supply your fragment with information
    public static DialogModificarAction newInstance(ArrayList<Action> ListaActions, ArrayList<AccionDefinida> ListaAccionesDefinidas, ArrayList<EventoDefinido> ListaEventosDefinidos, Action ActionAModificar)
    {
        DialogModificarAction myDialog = new DialogModificarAction();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList("ListaActions", ListaActions);
        args.putParcelableArrayList("ListaAccionesDefinidas", ListaAccionesDefinidas);
        args.putParcelableArrayList("ListaEventosDefinidos", ListaEventosDefinidos);
        args.putParcelable("ActionAModificar", ActionAModificar);
        myDialog.setArguments(args);
        return myDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0); // Le saca el título al DialogFragment

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_modif_baja_action, container);

        //DECLARO LOS ELEMENTOS EN EL LAYOUT
        ActionAModificar = getArguments().getParcelable("ActionAModificar");
        ListaAccionesDefinidas = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("ListaAccionesDefinidas");
        ListaEventosDefinidos = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("ListaEventosDefinidos");

        spinnerAccion = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerAccionDefinida);
        spinnerEvento = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerEventoDefinido);

        AccionDefinida AccionTemporal;
        for(int i = 0; i<= ListaAccionesDefinidas.size()-1;i++)
        {
            AccionTemporal = ListaAccionesDefinidas.get(i);
            ListaNombresAccionesDefinidas.add(AccionTemporal.getNombre());
        }

        EventoDefinido EventoTemporal;
        for(int i = 0; i<= ListaEventosDefinidos.size()-1;i++)
        {
            EventoTemporal = ListaEventosDefinidos.get(i);
            ListaNombresEventosDefinidos.add(EventoTemporal.getNombre());
        }


        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ListaNombresAccionesDefinidas);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerAccion.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinnerAccion.setSelection(ActionAModificar.getIdAccionDefinida()-1);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ListaNombresEventosDefinidos);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerEvento.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
        spinnerEvento.setSelection(ActionAModificar.getIdEventoDefinido()-1);

        //Setup cancel button listener
        cancelButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //Cerrar diálogo y no hacer nada
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });

        //Setup confirm button listener
        confirmButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.confirmButton);
        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //Obtengo los ids de la accion y el evento
                int IdAccionDefinidaSeleccionada;
                int IdEventoDefinidoSeleccionado;

                IdAccionDefinidaSeleccionada = ListaAccionesDefinidas.get(getIndex(spinnerAccion, ListaNombresAccionesDefinidas)).getId();
                IdEventoDefinidoSeleccionado = ListaEventosDefinidos.get(getIndex(spinnerEvento, ListaNombresEventosDefinidos)).getId();
                ActionAModificar.setIdAccionDefinida(IdAccionDefinidaSeleccionada);
                ActionAModificar.setIdEventoDefinido(IdEventoDefinidoSeleccionado);

                ActividadPrincipal.listaActions.get(ActionAModificar.getId()).setIdAccionDefinida(IdAccionDefinidaSeleccionada);
                ActividadPrincipal.listaActions.get(ActionAModificar.getId()).setIdEventoDefinido(IdEventoDefinidoSeleccionado);

                //Agrego la Action a la base de datos
                ActionsSQLite helper1  = new ActionsSQLite(getActivity(), "Actions", null, 1);
                SQLiteDatabase db = helper1.getWritableDatabase();
                String myQuery = "UPDATE Actions SET IdAccionDefinida = " + String.valueOf(IdAccionDefinidaSeleccionada) + ", IdEventoDefinido = " + String.valueOf(IdEventoDefinidoSeleccionado) + " WHERE Id = " + String.valueOf(ActionAModificar.getId());
                db.execSQL(myQuery);

                ActividadPrincipal parent = (ActividadPrincipal) getActivity();
                parent.listView.invalidateViews();
                //Cerrar diálogo
                getDialog().dismiss();


            }
        });

        deleteButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String query = "DELETE FROM Actions WHERE Id = " + String.valueOf(ActionAModificar.getId());
                ActionsSQLite helper1  = new ActionsSQLite(getActivity(), "Actions", null, 1);
                SQLiteDatabase db = helper1.getWritableDatabase();
                db.execSQL(query);
                Log.e("Listener del switch", "Query ejecutado");
                ActividadPrincipal.listaActions.remove(ActionAModificar.getId()-1);
                ActividadPrincipal.adapterActions.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //Cerrar diálogo
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof DialogModificarActionListener) 
        {
            dialogListener = (DialogModificarActionListener) activity; 
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement dialogListener.DialogActionsListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        ActividadPrincipal parent = (ActividadPrincipal) getActivity();
        parent.ActualizarActions();

    }
}
```

Comment: post more code, okay..

Comment: Code added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the data in the list, you must invoke the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged` method for proper operation.

You may have another bug aside from this, but `notifyDataSetChanged` is definitely required. Add that first, and then continue troubleshooting if you still have a problem.

Edit: Now that you've shown your code, I'm not surprised that it doesn't work. You've apparently jumbled up several concepts that should be separate entities. In particular, you should not be doing database access from an Adapter.

I'm not willing to spend the time to try to fully understand your code, which, quite frankly, is a mess, so let me instead describe how this *should* be approached.

There are two basic scenarios. In the first scenario, you have a List of objects, and want to show them in a ListView. In the second scenario, you have objects in the database, and want to show them in a ListView. The two scenarios should probably not be mixed.

In the first (simpler) scenario, you simply construct a ListAdapter, and give the list to the adapter. In this scenario, if you delete an item from the list, you must also invoke the ListAdapter's notifyDataSetChanged() method. If you want this deletion to persist beyond the current run of the application, you are on your own to update the original source of your list.

In the second case, you would obtain a Cursor from the database, probably using a CursorLoader, probably obtained from a ContentProvider. Then, you would create a CursorAdapter, and use that with the ListView. In this scenario, you ask the ContentProvider to delete the item from the database, and this will automatically cause the ContentProvider to update the Cursor, and will notify your activity. You then give the new cursor to the CursorAdapter, and call it's notifyDataSetChanged method.

There are many tutorials on the web for how to do this - I'd suggest reading up and checking out some examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where should I code this `notifyDataSetChanged()` and where should I invoke it?

Comment: As soon as you modify the list, call your adapter's notifyDataSetChanged method.

Comment: But I can't make a static reference to its method, what can I do?

Comment: I invoke it when I remove an object from the list, but It still does the same, any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Please explain the problem in more detail, and show us the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll start looking for that CursorAdapter that you talk about.